# Is there a way to filter outputs so that only the largest number is given?

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
     
        System.out.println ("Please Enter Your Integer");
         int X = input.nextInt();
         int X1 = input.nextInt();
         for(int i = 1; i <= X && i <= X1; i++) 
            { 
                 if(X%i==0 && X1%i==0) { 
                     int GCD = i;
                     System.out.printf("GCD of %d and %d is: %d", X, X1, GCD);  
                  
                 }
            }
    
    }
}
```

`

The problem with this code is that the for function runs the program all the way and all common divisors get printed and I want to filter the smaller numbers and only print the largest common divisor.

I tried reversing the for function but that screws up the Eucladian Algorithim

Comment: Reverse the loop, start from the highest possible number instead of 0 and count down. Once you fulfill your condition, just exit the loop.

Comment: What do you mean by "I want to filter the smaller numbers"?

Comment: filter the smaller numbers so if X =12 and X1 = 144 i dont want any other value other than 12

Answer (score 1):

Moving the `GCD` variable declaration before for loop and print statement after, it should work. As GCD is largest number that divides both `x` and `x1` at the end of the loop.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
         Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
     
         System.out.println ("Please Enter Your Integer");
         int X = input.nextInt();
         int X1 = input.nextInt();
         int GCD = 1;
         for(int i = 1; i <= X && i <= X1; i++) 
            { 
                 if(X%i==0 && X1%i==0) { 
                     GCD = i;
                 }
            }
          
         System.out.printf("%d", GCD);
    
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you this worked very well, I don't know why it doesn't break when you pulled GCD out of the if function

Answer (score 0):

You could invoke a helper function:

```
int gcdByEuclidsAlgorithm(int n1, int n2) {
    if (n2 == 0) {
        return n1;
    }
    return gcdByEuclidsAlgorithm(n2, n1 % n2);
}
```

This would return GCD and has better time complexity.

Comment: I ran this through my compiler and it didn't work because Its required that it takes 2 inputted numbers and the code broke when i added inputs

Comment: It's working: https://pastebin.com/pNkpeA7Z
Could you please share the error that you are getting?

Comment: Main.java:10: error: ';' expected
        int gcdByEuclidsAlgorithm(int n1, int n2) {
                                 ^
Main.java:10: error: <identifier> expected
        int gcdByEuclidsAlgorithm(int n1, int n2) {
                                         ^
Main.java:10: error: ';' expected
        int gcdByEuclidsAlgorithm(int n1, int n2) {
                                                ^
3 errors


** Process exited - Return Code: 1 **